# Why does regression of an outcome variable against a binary predictor variable where 1 implies the outcome, result in coefficients less than 1?

Tags: regression

I am looking at a fertility dataset and have the following variables:

- `kids` is 1 if a mom had more than 2 kids, 0 otherwise.
- `multi2nd` is 1 if the 2nd and 3rd children are twins, 0 otherwise.
- `age` is the age of mom.
- `agebirth` is the age of mom at time of the birth of her first child.
- `blackm` is 1 if mom is black, 0 otherwise.

I then regressed (OLS) `kids` against `multi2nd`, `age`, `agebirth`, `blackm`. The coefficient I got for `multi2nd` was around 0.7. However, I am wondering why this isn't 1, since if we have `multi2nd` for an individual, wouldn't it necessarily imply `kids`=1?

Comment: The coefficient for any predictor typically depends on the other predictors. In any case, having twins implies 2 or more children, but having 2 or more children doesn't imply having twins. which is the relevant way round.

Comment: I thought it would only address one direction, is there a way to intuitive understand why the other directions needs to be satisfied too? e.g. having 2 or more children doesn't imply twins

Comment: My parents had two children. We are not twins.  I am not sure what explanation you need there. But the point is not whether a regression catches causal relationships, and only causal relationships, because it does nothing of the kind. The yet bigger point remains my first, that what else is the equation affects what estimates you see.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of get what you mean: if the second and third children are twins, then the mother must have had more than two children. However, the mother also has nonzero values for the other features. She is not zero years old. She was not zero years old when she gave birth. She might be Black. Since all of these features could contribute to the outcome when the mother did not have twins, their coefficients are probably nonzero. Consequently, when you then turn on the “twins” variable (set it to one), the model would overestimate the outcome of the “twins” coefficient were one. Thus, the coefficient estimation lowers the “twins” coefficient, allowing for more accurate predictions.